# How do you retain original column for comparison in full_join() of two databases in r

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, tidyverse, audit

I am trying to compare two data frames in order to determine discrepancies in one of the columns.  To achieve this, I am using `full_join()` from tidyverse but I can't figure out how to retain the origin of the data frame so I can understand the discrepancy.

```
#Two databases that differ in Charge for the name and date or also have a entirely unique rows

df1 <- tibble(Name = c("JANE,DOE", "JANE,DOE", "JIM,DOE", "JANE,BUCK", "JIM,BUCK", "JIM,BUCK"),
Date = c("1/1/21", "1/10/21", "2/1/21", "1/2/21", "2/2/21", "2/8/21"),
Charge = c(-500, -500, -450, 0, -450, 0))

df2 <- tibble(Name = c("JANE,DOE", "JANE,DOE", "JIM,DOE", "JANE,BUCK", "JIM,BUCK", "JIM,BUCK", "JIM,BUCK"),
Date = c("1/2/21", "1/10/21", "2/1/21", "1/2/21", "2/2/21", "2/8/21", "2/10/21"),
Charge = c(-500, -500, -450, -500, -500, -500, -50))
```

I have tried to use combine them and then identify distinct rows

```
Audit <- full_join(df1,df2)
Audit <- Audit %>% distinct() %>% arrange(Name, Date)
```

But my output doesn't let me then contrast charges from rows where Name and Date are unique.

```
Name       Date    Charge
<chr>      <chr>   <dbl>
JANE,BUCK   1/2/21  0       #df2
JANE,BUCK   1/2/21  -500    #df1    
JANE,DOE    1/1/21  -500    #df1    
JANE,DOE    1/10/21 -500    #df1 & df2  
JANE,DOE    1/2/21  -500    #df2    
JIM,BUCK    2/10/21 -50     #df2
JIM,BUCK    2/2/21  -450    #df1    
JIM,BUCK    2/2/21  -500    #df2    
JIM,BUCK    2/8/21  0       #df1
JIM,BUCK    2/8/21  -500    #df2    
JIM,DOE     2/1/21  -450    #df1
```

What I am ultimately trying to achieve is an audit the generates output like this

```
Name       Date    Charge   ChargeDiff
<chr>      <chr>   <dbl>     <dbl>
JANE,BUCK   1/2/21  0       -500 #difference in Charge when name and date are same, but Charge differs
    
JANE,DOE    1/1/21  -500      0  #unique df1 is 0 because we know it is valid

JANE,DOE    1/2/21  -500    -500 #unique in df2 is -500 because it is missing   
JIM,BUCK    2/10/21 -50     -50  #unique in df2 is -50 because it is missing
JIM,BUCK    2/2/21  -450     50  # df1-df2 on 2/2 is -450-(-500) 

JIM,BUCK    2/8/21  0       500  # df1-df2

JIM,DOE     2/1/21  -450    #df1 #unique in df1
```

I am having a little trouble with the step I need to get the **ChangeDiff** column created. Is thera a different join option that allows me to add unique rows from df2 only to Audit, but retains unique Charge values from df2 in a separate column aligned on Name and Date.

Comment: While it isn't exactly what you're looking for, `waldo::compare()` is a good option for the interim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there with the `full_join()`
Using the `by()` argument allows you to control the join so that you can include both sets of `Charge` in separate columns. Use `dplyr::mutate()` and/or `case_when()` to generate your `ChargeDiff` column.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
tib <- 
  df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = c("Name" = "Name", "Date" = "Date")) %>% 
  mutate(ChargDiff = case_when(is.na(Charge.x) | is.na(Charge.y) ~ NA_real_,
                               TRUE ~ Charge.x - Charge.y))

tib
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>   Name      Date    Charge.x Charge.y ChargDiff
#>   <chr>     <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 JANE,DOE  1/1/21      -500       NA        NA
#> 2 JANE,DOE  1/10/21     -500     -500         0
#> 3 JIM,DOE   2/1/21      -450     -450         0
#> 4 JANE,BUCK 1/2/21         0     -500       500
#> 5 JIM,BUCK  2/2/21      -450     -500        50
#> 6 JIM,BUCK  2/8/21         0     -500       500
#> 7 JANE,DOE  1/2/21        NA     -500        NA
#> 8 JIM,BUCK  2/10/21       NA      -50        NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and works on my larger problem.  ```case_when()``` is something I need to learn to use more!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is doesn't look pretty -- coding-wise; but it will make a "pretty" table.
The table will show in the viewer pane in RStudio and be as wide as the viewer is.

```
require(htmlTable)
require(compareDF)


# adds color
emph <- function(xCd){
  
  # create empty matrix
  css.cell = matrix(nrow = dim(xCd)[1], 
                    ncol = dim(xCd)[2] + 1)  # another column will be added for origin
  
  # for + add #003b70; for - add #b21e28
  where <- which(xCd == "+",   # origin in the first table
                 arr.ind = T)  # get dim loc
  css.cell[where] <- "font-weight:bold;color:#003b70;padding-left:1em;padding-right:1em;"

  where2 <- which(xCd == "-",  # origin in the second table
                  arr.ind = T)
  css.cell[where2] <- "font-weight:bold;color:#b21e28;padding-left:1em;padding-right:1em;"
  
  where3 <- which(css.cell == NA, 
                  arr.ind = T)
  css.cell[where3] <- "padding-left:1em;padding-right:1em;"
       # add padding for every where else; this sets a minimum width

  return(css.cell)
} # end udf
```

Create the table

```
# creates table
fmtStyle <- function(frame1, frame2){
  # create the comparison
  comp <- compare_df(frame1, frame2,
                     keep_unchanged_rows = T)      # create the comparison
  
  # don't include rowname & chng_type columns-- 3 through the rest of the columns
  # keeps both frames' rows even if they're the same data; don't keep in this table
  compMat <- as.matrix(comp$comparison_table_diff[c(rownames(unique(comp[[1]]))),    
                                                  3:ncol(comp$comparison_table_diff)]) 
  css <- emph(compMat)    # collect colors
  
  # collect the joined data
  # don't include rowname & chng_type columns-- 3 through the rest of the columns
  # keeps both frames' rows even if they're the same data; don't keep in this table
  mat <- as.matrix(comp$comparison_table_ts2char[c(rownames(unique(comp[[1]]))),
                                                 3:ncol(comp$comparison_table_ts2char)])
  rownames(mat) <- NULL   # remove the rownames (they aren't meaningful)
  
  # make the data character type; the date column being an exception
  mat[,3] <- txtRound(mat[,3],0)  # make all values character data
  
  # add a column identifying origin
  Origins <- ifelse(comp$comparison_table_diff[c(rownames(unique(comp[[1]]))),
                                               ]$chng_type == "+", "df1",
                    ifelse(comp$comparison_table_diff[c(rownames(unique(comp[[1]]))),
                                                      ]$chng_type == "-", "df2",
                           "df1 & df2"))    

  # add origins to the matrix
  mat <- cbind(mat, Origins)
  
  # make it pretty
  soPretty <- mat %>% 
    addHtmlTableStyle(spacer.celltype = "double_cell",
                      css.cell = css, 
                      css.header = "font-weight: normal",
                      pos.caption = "bottom") %>% 
    htmlTable(cgroup = list(c("Comparison Audit")),
              n.cgroup = list(c(ncol(mat))),   # span the name cgroup words over all the columns
              caption = paste0("<i>Note</i>: Blue font indicates an origin that only exists in the first table;",
                               " where a red font indicates that the information is unique to the second table."))
                     # paste is used in the caption just make the caption readable in the script file
  return(soPretty)
} # end table creation function
```

To use the functions, call it this way

```
# using it
(showMe <- fmtStyle(df1,df2))
```

To see the HTML behind the table or to modify it you can see the script this way

```
as.character(showMe)
```

[image]

Comment: this is a very impressive table!  I had not considered operating on the data frames as a matrix and putting together as a html table--very helpful!

Comment: Glad you like it!